# Thrift java client cannot handle union properly

Tags: java, c++, thrift, unions

Dead simple thrift union example.
Env: latest thrift, cpp as server, java as client
`mytest.thrift`:

```
namespace java com.wilbeibi.thrift

union Value {
  1: i16     i16_v,
  2: string  str_v,
}

struct Box {
  1: Value value;
}

service MyTest {
  Box echoUnion(1: i32 number);
}
```

`C++ server code:`

```
#include "MyTest.h"
#include <thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h>
#include <thrift/server/TSimpleServer.h>
#include <thrift/transport/TServerSocket.h>
#include <thrift/transport/TBufferTransports.h>

using namespace ::apache::thrift;
using namespace ::apache::thrift::protocol;
using namespace ::apache::thrift::transport;
using namespace ::apache::thrift::server;

using boost::shared_ptr;

class MyTestHandler : virtual public MyTestIf {
 public:
  MyTestHandler() {
    // Your initialization goes here
  }

  void echoUnion(Box& _return, const int32_t number) {
    // Your implementation goes here
  printf("Into echoUnion\n");
  if (number % 2 == 0) {
    Value v;
    v.__set_i16_v(100);
    v.__isset.i16_v = true;
    _return.__set_value(v);
    printf("Even number set int32\n");
  } else {
    Value v;
    v.__set_str_v("String value");
    v.__isset.str_v = true;
    _return.__set_value(v);
    printf("Odd number set string\n");
  }
    printf("echoUnion\n");
  }

};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int port = 9090;
  shared_ptr<MyTestHandler> handler(new MyTestHandler());
  shared_ptr<TProcessor> processor(new MyTestProcessor(handler));
  shared_ptr<TServerTransport> serverTransport(new TServerSocket(port));
  shared_ptr<TTransportFactory> transportFactory(new TBufferedTransportFactory());
  shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocolFactory());

  TSimpleServer server(processor, serverTransport, transportFactory, protocolFactory);
  printf("Server is running on %d\n", port);
  server.serve();
  return 0;
}
```

`java client code`:

```
// some imports here
public class Client {
    public void startClient() {
        TTransport transport;
            try {
               transport = new TSocket("localhost", 9090);
               TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
               MyTest.Client client = new MyTest.Client(protocol);
               transport.open();
               Box box = client.echoUnion(1);              
               System.out.println(box.toString());

               Box box2 = client.echoUnion(2);
               System.out.println(box2.toString());

               transport.close();
           } catch (TTransportException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (TException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
           Client client = new Client();
           client.startClient();
       }
}
```

Somehow, java client cannot print out string properly. (I also wrote a python client, but that seems work)

Full code on gist here: [thrift file, c++ and java code](https://gist.github.com/Wilbeibi/ee05f49c00d33d973558)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you are observing [`THRIFT-1833`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1833) bug which cause compiler to produce invalid C++ code for union types.

In your case server writes both fields of union type while client always reads only first one - `i16_v` (remaining bytes are still resides in buffer). So second read never ends because it finds some unexpected data in buffer.

You can can use `struct` instead of `union` and maintain single-field logic manually. Or you either can contribute/wait till bug will be fixed.

The last option is applying a patch on incorrectly generated C++ source code like this:

```
--- mytest_types.cpp    2016-02-26 20:02:57.210652969 +0300
+++ mytest_types.cpp.old   2016-02-26 20:02:39.650652742 +0300 
@@ -80,13 +80,17 @@
apache::thrift::protocol::TOutputRecursionTracker tracker(*oprot);
xfer += oprot->writeStructBegin("Value");

-  xfer += oprot->writeFieldBegin("i16_v", ::apache::thrift::protocol::T_I16, 1);
-  xfer += oprot->writeI16(this->i16_v);
-  xfer += oprot->writeFieldEnd();
+  if (this->__isset.i16_v) {
+    xfer += oprot->writeFieldBegin("i16_v", ::apache::thrift::protocol::T_I16, 1);
+    xfer += oprot->writeI16(this->i16_v);
+    xfer += oprot->writeFieldEnd();
+  }

-  xfer += oprot->writeFieldBegin("str_v", ::apache::thrift::protocol::T_STRING, 2);
-  xfer += oprot->writeString(this->str_v);
-  xfer += oprot->writeFieldEnd();
+  if (this->__isset.str_v) {
+    xfer += oprot->writeFieldBegin("str_v", ::apache::thrift::protocol::T_STRING, 2);
+    xfer += oprot->writeString(this->str_v);
+    xfer += oprot->writeFieldEnd();
+  }
```